# PayloadValidatingInterceptor not firing

Tags: spring-ws

I have been struggling with PayloadValidatingInterceptor, I am using spring 3.2 and in my webservice I only have Request as my service is fire and forget.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd">

PayloadValidatingInterceptor is not firing at all: here is the configuration:

     <sws:interceptors>

    <bean id="validatingInterceptor"        
      class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">     
      <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/erass-ingest.xsd"/>     
      <property name="validateRequest" value="true"/>     
      <property name="validateResponse" value="false"/> </bean>   

    </sws:interceptors>
```

this is a header of my XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/erass/schema/ingest" xmlns:common="http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/erass/schema/common" targetNamespace="http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/erass/schema/ingest" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="0.4">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/erass/schema/common" schemaLocation="erass-common-types.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/erass/schema/common" schemaLocation="erass-simple-types.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="IngestionData">
```

and here is my endpoint:

```
@Endpoint
public class IngestionEndpoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IngestionEndpoint.class);

    private static final String INGESTION_REQUEST = "IngestionData";

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/erass/schema/ingest";

    @Autowired
    private IngestionService service;

    public IngestionEndpoint() {
        super();
    }

    public IngestionEndpoint(IngestionService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(localPart = INGESTION_REQUEST, namespace=NAMESPACE_URI)    
    public void handleIngestRequest(@RequestPayload IngestionData data) {
        try {
            service.ingest(data);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("An error occurred ingesting data XXX", t);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file is missing important elements:

```
<!-- The package containing your endpoint-->
<context:component-scan base-package="...."/> 
<sws:annotation-driven/>
```

Both lines helps spring-ws [support your endpoind and its annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html).